# Get notified when new account is created

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are looking to develop a users directory and it should create new record whenever a new Google Apps account is created. Is there any way to listen for these changes? I was thinking to go for polling via https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users but it is not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Account activity alerts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3230421) notify admins of changes to the domain. Alerts can be sent when new user accounts are created. Alerts can be checked in the Control Panel, admin email or via the [directory.notifications](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/notifications) API calls.

*Update*: thinking about this a little more, it probably makes more sense to use the Admin SDK Reports API for this. With the [Admin Activity API call](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin#get_all_events), you can even limit returned results to a specific event like user creation.

Comment: Thanks Jay! With the Admin Activity API call, Do you see any way to have those notifications pushed to external system so we don't need to poll them?

Comment: There is no push method, you'll need to poll for changes at regular intervals.

Comment: Thank you Jay! That should help.